# Django Templates - pass %block% data to included template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got nested template file, and data from template doesn't shows

template.html

```
<body>
{% block main_block %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

main.html

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
....
{% block include_data %}
NOT SHOWN DATA
{% endblock %}

{% block main_block %}
some_data
{% include "child.html" %}
some_data
{% endblock %}
```

child.html

```
<div>
<tags></tags>
{% block include_data %}
that will shown, but i wanna to be shown "NO SHOWN DATA"
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

How it can be solved?

Comment: You can either extend the endblock of include_data or use the "with" operator to pass the data to the next block.

Comment: Show template.html

Comment: Ванюх )))
<body>
{% block main_block %}
{% endblock %}
</body>

Comment: The root template `template.html` knows about one block only: `main_block`. Template engine has no idea where is `include_data` block supposed to be placed. Put `include_data` block into the ancestor template (`template.html`) or move it inside `main_block` in `main.html` and your data will appear on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The [`block.super` variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) can be used to get the content of the block from the parent template:

```
<div>
<tags></tags>
{% block include_data %}
{{ block.super }}
...appeding content to the block...
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: 'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'. Did you use {{ block.super }} in a base template?

Comment: No, you need to use this at the child template.

Comment: I did that and got such error